# CSS - How do I align my divs horizontally?

Tags: html, css

I am a HTML/CSS beginner, who wants to create four colored boxes an align them horizontally. I was able to build those four boxes individually. Yet, I do have to comment boxes 2-4 out because they overlap each other. Does someone in this community has the answer to my newb problem?

The divs should ultimately look like the one in the picture below:

[image]

Here is my code:

```css
body {

}

#box-grey {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  }
#box-grey #box-orange {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  fixed: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}
/*
#box-black {
  background-color: black;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  }
#box-black #box-yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}

#box-blue {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  }
#box-blue #box-green {
  background-color: green;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  right: 0px;
}

#box-purple {
  background-color: purple;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  }
#box-purple #box-pink {
  background-color: pink;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    <title>Boxes</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="box-grey">
      <div id="box-orange"</div>
      </div>
    <div id="box-black">
      <div id="box-yellow"</div>
      </div>
    <div id="box-blue">
      <div id="box-green"</div>
      </div>
    <div id="box-purple">
      <div id="box-pink"</div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: to start you need to correct your code

Comment: You are missing closing tags of all the inner divs.

Comment: Use CSS Grid!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's rather usual solution without modern css3 `grid` and `flex` abilities. We can set `display: inline-block` and `position: relative` for wrapper boxes, after that we set `position: absolute` for inner boxes and positioning them to corners.

```css
body {
  min-width: 840px;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.box-inner {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}

#box-grey {
  background-color: grey;
}
#box-grey #box-orange {
  background-color: orange;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
#box-black {
  background-color: black;
}
#box-black #box-yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#box-blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
#box-blue #box-green {
  background-color: green;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#box-purple {
  background-color: purple;
}
#box-purple #box-pink {
  background-color: pink;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    <title>Boxes</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="box-grey" class="box">
      <div id="box-orange" class="box-inner"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="box-black" class="box">
      <div id="box-yellow" class="box-inner"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="box-blue" class="box">
      <div id="box-green" class="box-inner"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="box-purple" class="box">
      <div id="box-pink" class="box-inner"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you add an explanation of what you've done, and why, it's worth an upvote.

Comment: @ADyson No problem, I added description for my solution.

Answer (score 2):

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 1em;
}

#box-1,
#box-2,
#box-3,
#box-4 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

#box-1 {
  background-color: grey;
}

#box-2 {
  background-color: black;
}

#box-3 {
  background-color: blue;
}

#box-4 {
  background-color: purple;
}

#box-grey {
  background-color: grey;
}

#box-orange {
  background-color: orange;
}

#box-black {
  background-color: black;
}

#box-blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

#box-purple {
  background-color: purple;
}

#box-yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#box-green {
  background-color: green;
}

#box-pink {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
  <title>Boxes</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="box-1">
      <div></div>
      <div id="box-orange">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="box-2">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div id="box-yellow"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="box-3">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div id="box-green"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="box-4">
      <div id="box-pink"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Using CSS Grid Approach! Easier to Understand!

Answer (score 1):

You have issues with your code. You have lots of unclosed `<div>`. Try this code.

```css
body {}

.box-wrap {
  display: flex;
}

#box-grey {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

#box-grey #box-orange {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#box-black {
  background-color: black;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

#box-black #box-yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#box-blue {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

#box-blue #box-green {
  background-color: green;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0px;
}

#box-purple {
  background-color: purple;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

#box-purple #box-pink {
  background-color: pink;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  ;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
  <title>Boxes</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="box-wrap">
    <div id="box-grey">
      <div id="box-orange"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="box-black">
      <div id="box-yellow"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="box-blue">
      <div id="box-green"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="box-purple">
      <div id="box-pink"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: good idea (for those browsers which support flexbox). You should probably actually explain what you've done though, and why. It will not be obvious to someone with relatively beginner level of CSS experience, which seems as though it may be the case here. P.S. I made your code runnable so it can be demo'd easily.

Comment: Great, didn't recognize that there where so many <div's> unclosed. With the additional class and the display: flex argument everything seems to be fine! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @dannisN86 happy to help mate. if my answer solves your issue, how about accepting my answer...cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

To get the boxes to align horizontally one very simple solution is to set a `float:left` on all of them. If the screen is not wide enough to display them all horizontally, then those which do not fit will automatically be pushed to the next line.

To achieve this in your code I've put a class called "outer-box" on all the outer divs, and then set a rule in CSS that all elements with this class will be floated left. This stops them being block-level elements (i.e. block-level elements which always cause a new line to be started).

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float for more in-depth documentation of floats.

```css
body {}

.outer-box {
  float: left;
}

#box-grey {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

#box-grey #box-orange {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  fixed: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}



#box-black {
  background-color: black;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  }
#box-black #box-yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}

#box-blue {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  }
#box-blue #box-green {
  background-color: green;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  right: 0px;
}

#box-purple {
  background-color: purple;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  }
#box-purple #box-pink {
  background-color: pink;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
  <title>Boxes</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="box-grey" class="outer-box">
    <div id="box-orange"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="box-black" class="outer-box">
    <div id="box-yellow"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="box-blue" class="outer-box">
    <div id="box-green"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="box-purple" class="outer-box">
    <div id="box-pink"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Could you explain why you would choose `float` over `display: inline-block`? I've seen it at more places and I'm just wondering why you've chosen `float`.

Comment: @DouwedeHaan do you think inline-block is superior for any reason? In this particular case it probably wouldn't make a huge difference to the outcome, unless I've forgotten something. I just tend to use floats for this kind of thing, that's all. You're welcome to propose an alternative answer.

Comment: @DouwedeHaan Disadvantage of inline-block it that it will put the boxes in a text flow, and suddenly the whitespace between them will show up, and you have to work around that (by modifying the HTML, or hack something with font size). Still, I wouldn't use float either and go for flexbox nowadays. 
ADyson It really looks like he's just asking for clarification. It's in no way critisism to your answer.

Comment: @ADyson I've always used inline-block with font-size 0 and it just felt right. If you float some elements to the right, the order gets reversed (like a menu), which is mainly the reason I avoid floats. I only use them for images in text. Don't see it as an attack towards your answer, which is perfect, but I was just curious about your reasoning!

Comment: @DouwedeHaan well I agree float right can get confusing, but as long as you know the behaviour, it's not so bad. And I tend to float everything one way in this kind of scenario, especially since the screen width is not known. Like Golez I've also started using flexbox quite a bit as well instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this css

```css
#box-grey {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  float:left;
  margin:10px;
  }
#box-grey #box-orange {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  float:left;
  left: 100px;
}

#box-black {
  background-color: black;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  float:left;
  margin:10px;
  }
#box-black #box-yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  float:left;
}

#box-blue {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  float:left;
  margin:10px;
  }
#box-blue #box-green {
  background-color: green;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  right: 0px;
  float:left;
}

#box-purple {
  background-color: purple;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float:left;
  margin:10px;
  }
#box-purple #box-pink {
  background-color: pink;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div id="box-grey">
      <div id="box-orange"></div>
      </div>
    <div id="box-black">
      <div id="box-yellow"></div>
      </div>
    <div id="box-blue">
      <div id="box-green"></div>
      </div>
    <div id="box-purple">
      <div id="box-pink"></div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added classes to the divs to manage code better.

```css
body {}

.outerbox {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 24%;
  position: relative;
}

.innerbox {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

#box-grey {
  background-color: grey;
}

#box-grey #box-orange {
  background-color: orange;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#box-black {
  background-color: black;
}

#box-black #box-yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

#box-blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

#box-blue #box-green {
  background-color: green;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

#box-purple {
  background-color: purple;
}

#box-purple #box-pink {
  background-color: pink;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
  <title>Boxes</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="box-grey" class="outerbox">
    <div id="box-orange" class="innerbox"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="box-black" class="outerbox">
    <div id="box-yellow" class="innerbox"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="box-blue" class="outerbox">
    <div id="box-green" class="innerbox"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="box-purple" class="outerbox">
    <div id="box-pink" class="innerbox"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing closing tag of the `div`.

Also just put a `display: flex` in your CSS.

See working example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wjqmOK

Answer (score 0):

Example using flexbox

```css
        .parent {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
        }
        .child {
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
        }
        .child:nth-child(1) {
            background-color: pink;
        }
        .child:nth-child(2) {
            background-color: green;
        }
        .child:nth-child(3) {
            background-color: blue;
        }
```

```html
  <div class="parent">
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: May you wrap your answer as a workable snippet? So it will be valuable answer for `flex` example.

Comment: But this is not exactly topicstarter's case. It may be applied for wrapper boxes of course.

Comment: It's exactly the case and it can be applied easily. He even accepted that as the solution

Answer (score 0):

Horizontal boxes can be done in a variety of ways.

1. You can use float: left on the box class or display: inline-block

   ```
   .box {
    float: left; // comment out this or display: inline-block
    display: inline-block; // comment out this or float: left
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
   }

   .box.grey {
    background-color: #808080;
   }

   .box.black{
    background-color: #000000;
   }

   .box.blue{
    background-color: #0000FF;
   }

   .box.purple{
    background-color: #810081;
   }

   .inner-box{
    position: absolute;
   }

   .inner-box.orange{
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #FFA600;
   }

   .inner-box.yellow{
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #FFFF00;
   }

   .inner-box.green{
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #008100;
   }

   .inner-box.pink{
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #FFC0CB;
   }
   ```
2. You can wrap the box divs in another wrapper and utilise flexbox

   .boxes {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
   }

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
        <title>Boxes</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="box grey">
          <div class="inner-box orange"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="box grey">
          <div class="inner-box yellow"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="box blue">
          <div class="inner-box green"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="box purple">
          <div class="inner-box pink"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I also suggest using classes instead of ids unless you are planning and affecting the dom with js at some point

Answer (score -1):

try this on {body} or {*} to apply for all div elements :-

```
body
{
margin: auto;
vertical-align: center;
text-align: center;
}

//if you apply on this div only
#box-blue 
{
background-color: blue;
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
margin: auto;
vertical-align: center;
text-align: center;
}
```

can you apply this codes and tell me the result, it's right for you.

Comment: why don't you tell us the result? Since you suggested it, you must know? You can even make a runnable demo within your answer using the Snippets feature, so we can see it easily.

Answer (score -1):

With Aryans additional "class" I could finally get the desired outcome! Added a *margin:right 5px;* to get the spacing between the boxes right. Problem solved - thank you!

Comment: Don't add "thanks" type answers. Accept and/or upvote the answer which worked. Or if you significantly changed it, post your own _complete_ answer showing the whole solution